# what is the diffrence between CMD java -version &> /staf-logs/output.log and CMD ["java -version &> /staf-logs/output.log"] in docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Iam  getting "/staf-logs/output.log" not found error  when using  "CMD ["java -version &> /staf-logs/output.log"]"  , i wish to redirect docker logs to output.log

Comment: Can you confirm if the dir `/staf-logs/output.log` exists? You can create this before the CMD command.

Comment: The CMD form as you've written it will try to run a binary named exactly `java -version &> /staf-logs/output.log` (with spaces, punctuation, and the log file name as part of the executable name); it's highly unlikely you have such a binary.

Answer (score 1):

You should let the app in the container write to stdout. You can then deal with the logs from outside the container using `docker logs <container>`. If you write to a file, then the file will disappear with the container and you'll not be able to find it unless you've mounted a volume either on the host or with docker volumes.